# Changing Default Parameter in pandas function call

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, python-import

In pandas, many functions take a long list of optional parameters, each with a default.

If I wanted to redefine a default across a whole project or at least across a whole py file is there an easy way to do this?

For example `read_csv()` defaults to `encoding=None`, but I'd like every call to `read_csv()` to default to `UTF-8` encoding.

I recognise I could wrap the function, but this feels ugly to have one Pandas call via a separate custom import.  Plus other developers will no doubt stray back to using `read_csv()`.

I know I could edit the pandas source code, but that's a very bad idea in terms of maintaining compatibility.

And finally obviously I can update every `read_csv()` call to individually set the encoding, but there are and awful lot of them in the project I'm working on, and it will be tricky to regex, due to the possibility of other optional non-positional parameters.  Also this doesn't help reign-in future developers repeating the same issue.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

MedAli's answer works well at file scope.

I'm stuck trying to get it to work at directory scope (I'm using Python 2.7):

I believe that *if* pandas was in the standard library it would be easy enough to ignore local files when importing things from the standard library:
`from __future__ import absolute_import`

Also this rather dodgy looking hack doesn't work either:

```
import sys                                                                                                                                                               
syspath = sys.path                                                                                                                                                        
new_syspath = [path for path in sys.path if path.strip('.')]                                                                                                                                                    
sys.path = new_syspath                                                                                                                                                     
import pandas                                                                                                                                                    
sys.path = syspath
```

I understand messing about with the sys.path is a bad idea, although because I'm actually trying to completely trample pandas by design, at least some of the usual concerns don't apply.

Plus as per comments below - as a testcase before making hundreds of search/replaces I think it's valid to find a way to mask the library without changing the code... and if it works then employing a less hacky solution.

It's starting to look not-doable, even using hacks, can anyone prove me wrong?

**2nd Edit:**

I'm fairly certain you cannot do what I've asked about in the first Edit, so I've accepted the file scope answer as the best you can do in Python.

In terms of doing a test run, I think the easiest thing to do is to change parsers.py in panadas temporarily, before applying the file scope level fix.

I'm still interested if anyone thinks otherwise!

Comment: There is no fool-proof method that can't be worked around. I'd just define your own wrapper and make it known that it sets the `encoding` param to default to 'utf-8' and leave it at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `functools.partial`

```
import pandas as pd 
import functools 

new_read_csv = functools.partial(pd.read_csv, encoding="utf-8")
```

Then you use `new_read_csv` as you would use `pd.read_csv`

You can also overwrite the `pd.read_csv` to hold the new function with the default parameter as follows:

```
pd.read_csv = new_read_csv
```

If you want to go back to the original implementation after overwriting it:

```
pd.read_csv = pd.read_csv.func
```

Comment: This is really nice - but it's missing the last bit - it'd then like to somehow superimpose this back onto pd.read_csv, hiding the original implementation (to some extent at least), rather than create a new function.

Comment: Thanks - yes, this works perfectly at file scope.  Is there anyway to get this to work at directory scope or even project scope?  I was exploring using import shadowing by having a pandas.py in my local source directory that would override the actual pandas import. It would then import * all of the actual pandas into it's own namespace and modify read_csv just as you've shown?  It doesn't seem to work tho, perhaps because it's rather hacky!  the shadowing works, but I can't see how to populate the local pandas namespace with the actual pandas namespace?

Comment: @Phil I'd personnaly favor not doing that at project scoop to avoid painful bugs due to changes in version and so on overtime. But import shadowing as you describe can be a workaround. I haven't tried it myself though..

Comment: Thanks -  I have the same reservations, but at least to test the change project-wide without making hundreds of changes, I think it's acceptable.  Whether I should leave it in place in production is not so straight forward!

Comment: I'm still trying to get it to work at directory scope.  There are solutions to this if panadas was a part of the standard library, but it's proving quite tricky to do otherwise.  I don't want to close the question off until I've exhausted this.  I'll update my questions shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested solution did not work for me in a similar case (`groupby`). However, reading the manual suggests that `partial` is for functions while `partialmethod` is for methods. If you want to change default pandas parameters on DataFrames, this is the amended code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import functools 

new_groupby = functools.partialmethod(pd.DataFrame.groupby, dropna=False)
pd.DataFrame.read_csv = new_groupby
```